# Confused in my Left Join

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm wracking my brain on this one and I think it is not quite as challenging as I'm making it out to be. Effectively what I am trying to do is:

Calculate the monthly average of sales while excluding the days that are holiday type 1 which apply to all regions (I can change this to Type 2 for a specific region, for example).

```
SELECT Year(Date) AS Year, Month(Date) AS Month, Avg(tblSales.Sales) AS AvgSales
FROM tblSales
LEFT JOIN tblHolidays
ON tblSales.[Date] >= tblHolidays.[Date From] AND tblSales.[Date] <= tblHolidays.[Date To] 
WHERE tblHolidays.[Date From] Is Null AND tblHolidays.[Type]<> 1 AND tblHolidays.[Region]<>"All"
GROUP BY Year(Date), Month(Date);
```

Right now I'm not sure that I understand whether or not this is working, while it does produce results. What I'm not seeing is where it is telling tblHolidays not to use Type 2 and Type 3 holidays, or holidays that apply to specific regions when comparing to tblSales.[Date].

Any ideas?

Comment: At first you need to do is join correctly your table "tblHolidays" and "tblSales" after on. Give the conditions after where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really what you mean.

```
SELECT Year(Date) AS Year, Month(Date) AS Month, Avg(tblSales.Sales) AS AvgSales
FROM tblSales
LEFT JOIN tblHolidays
     ON tblSales.[Date] >= tblHolidays.[Date From]
        AND tblSales.[Date] <= tblHolidays.[Date To]
        AND tblHolidays.[Type] = 1 AND tblHolidays.[Region] = "All"
WHERE tblHolidays.[Date From] Is Null
GROUP BY Year(Date), Month(Date);
```

The LEFT JOIN serves to bring in matches from tblHolidays where it matches tblSales on ALL the conditions in the `ON` clause.  In this case, it's saying:

1. Find holidays that covered the sales date, that are of type 1 and affect "all" regions.

Because of the LEFT JOIN nature, it will preserve all rows from tblSales even if no matches were found from tblHolidays.  Next, where the matches ***were*** found, we strike them off by using the filter `tblHolidays.[Date From] Is Null`.  Because `tblHolidays.[Date From]` is **not** null where the holiday condition was found.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I tried that one previously but I get an error in Access 2007 that says: JOIN expression not supported and it highlights "tblHolidays.[Type] = 1"

Comment: I think I found a solution:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ta/accessdev/thread/15c36745-f7a4-4926-9687-7161e5894468

You need to add parentheses after 'ON'